# Identification of an 8-pin IC marked YS17 RBSCK0 2022QED

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount, led-driver

Please help me identify an 8-pin IC marked ( **YS17 RBSCK0 2022QED** ),
i have a LED circuit in which this IC is burned out. Can anyone tell me the alternative of this IC. I searched the net but I couldn't find the part anywhere.
On this IC in the PCB where the negative and positive in-out points were coming. I have drawn them in the picture below

[image: LED Light SMD IC]
[image: Data as per PCB]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Padauk (应广科技)](http://www.padauk.com.tw) MCU, possibly a [PMS150C-S08](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810301810_PADAUK-Tech-PMS150C-S08_C129127.pdf). In this [thread on the eevblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/did-i-get-fake-padauk-pms150cs/) the poster asks if a SOP-8 IC with the marking

```
YS17
RBCWA5
1851XCD
```

is a genuine PMS150C and later gets the confirmation from Padauk. However, on [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Microcontroller-Units-MCUs-MPUs-SOCs_PADAUK-Tech-PMS150C-S08_C129127.html) the markings look completely different, so it's unclear to me if the markings really contain a product code or if they are just a lot number/date code. You will have to ask Padauk to confirm.

[image]

([Source: lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Microcontroller-Units-MCUs-MPUs-SOCs_PADAUK-Tech-PMS150C-S08_C129127.html))

Other Padauk parts have similar markings, so I think it's clearly the correct manufacturer. Here a PMS152-S08 as example:

[image]

(Source: lcsc.com)